# em's not working on iPhone Browser

Tags: iphone, html, css

Ive set my fonts specifically as follows

```
* {font-size: 1em;}
html {font-size: 125%;}
body{font-size: 50%;}
p, ul, ol{line-height:1.7em; font-size:1.2em; margin-bottom:0.5em; }
```

Works fine on desktop browsers, and iPad (viewing is identical) - however the font size does not get any smaller on the iphone?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just so you know, you should probably set the font size of 1em on the body, not star. For performance and semantic issues.

Comment: this was only an extract of my code, reduced for the purposes of pasting on here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. Either apply the WebKit-specific `text-size-adjust` property:

```
html {
  /* Prevent WebKit-based browsers from resizing the text: */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Or, you could define the viewport width in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This tells the browser that it should use a viewport width equal to the device’s physical width. In most cases this prevents weird in-document text zooming inconsistencies, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sharon, the first part is a solution to the problem, the second however does not solve it - I had tried this prior to the first solution. Accepting as valid solution for the first one :)